How to conduct statistical analysis on multiply imputed data?
I have a data.frame named mydata with 6 columns: status, times, t1, t2, t3, t4. However, t1, t2, t3, and t4 contain missing values in this dataset. I intend to impute these missing values using the mice package and then perform statistical analysis on the imputed data. The statistical analyses I need to conduct on mydata include:

Baseline characteristics table: Generate table1 using the gtsummary package.
Survival analysis: Build a Cox regression model.
ROC curve: Plot ROC curves.
Survival plot: Plot survival curves.

If using the original dataset (before imputation), the code for these statistical analyses is as follows:
# Baseline characteristics table
library(gtsummary)

tbl1 <- mydata %>%
  tbl_summary(by = status) %>%
  add_p()
print(tbl1)

# Cox regression model
library(survival)
surv_object <- Surv(mydata$times, mydata$status)
cox_model <- coxph(surv_object ~ t1 + t2 + t3 + t4, data = mydata)
summary(cox_model)

# ROC curve
library(pROC)
library(ggplot2)
roc_t1 <- roc(mydata$status, mydata$t1)
roc_t2 <- roc(mydata$status, mydata$t2)
roc_t3 <- roc(mydata$status, mydata$t3)
roc_t4 <- roc(mydata$status, mydata$t4)
ggroc <- ggplot() +
  geom_roc(data = roc_t1, aes(color = "t1")) +
  geom_roc(data = roc_t2, aes(color = "t2")) +
  geom_roc(data = roc_t3, aes(color = "t3")) +
  geom_roc(data = roc_t4, aes(color = "t4")) +
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  labs(title = "ROC Curves", x = "False Positive Rate", y = "True Positive Rate", color = "Predictor") +
  theme_minimal()
print(ggroc)

# Survival plot
library(survminer)

surv_fit <- survfit(surv_object ~ 1, data = mydata)

ggsurvplot(surv_fit,
           data = mydata,
           conf.int = TRUE,
           pval = TRUE, 
           surv.median.line = "hv",
           risk.table = TRUE,
           ggtheme = theme_classic())

After performing multiple imputation using the mice package, I obtain 5 imputed datasets. How should I proceed with generating table1, Cox regression, ROC curves, and survival curves?
library(mice)
imp_data <- mice(mydata, m = 5, maxit = 50, method = "pmm", seed = 500)

# Cox regression model
???

# ROC curve
???

# Survival plot
???


Upon reviewing various sources, I found several approaches:

Selecting one of the datasets for subsequent analysis (not recommended) complete_data <- complete(imp_data, 1)
Computing the mean or median of each observation across the five datasets to obtain a final dataset for analysis.
Summarizing the results of the models using with() %>% pool().

Which approach would be most appropriate? If using with() %>% pool() for statistical analysis, how should I adjust the code for generating table1, ROC curves, and survival curves, especially table1, ROC curves, and survival curves?

For the descriptive summaries I would absolutely use the original non-imputed data.

However, I have noticed in many academic papers that they include both the original non-imputed data and the imputed data in their descriptive summaries. Should I follow this approach?

One advantage of showing both is that it highlights if your imputation changed your marginal data distributions to an appreciable degree. I wouldn't know, I try to avoid imputation as much as I can, because it simply simulates knowledge we don't have. I try to use methods that don't rely on complete data. Unfortunately, I have no experience with your tools, so I can't really say more to your specific problem...

First, although multiple imputation is often highly favored, it isn't necessary if the fraction of missing data is small. Then single imputation might be adequate in practice. See Section 3.11 of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies. His case study of Cox regression in Chapter 21 uses single imputation to handle missing data.
If you are going to use multiple imputation, then you should follow Rubin's rules to pool estimates among the models of the imputed sets. For parameters whose estimates have normal distributions around the population values, like the coefficients of a Cox model, the point estimate is the average over all the models. The variance-covariance matrix is the sum of the average over all the models plus a term that represents the uncertainty arising from imputation. See Flexible Imputation of Missing Data (FIMD), Section 2.3.
That's what your Option 3 does. For the Cox regression coefficient estimates you will then have corresponding standard errors for the coefficients that include the uncertainty arising from imputations. The other options you suggest throw away the advantages of multiple imputation, as they reduce the multiply imputed data to a single set.
The Cox regression coefficients (or their transformations into hazard ratios) are typically of most interest. For ROC and survival curves, note that you can similarly pool values for any estimand that is close to normally distributed or can be transformed into such a form. See FIMD, Section 5.5.
If you just want to display an ROC curve, I don't see a problem in displaying the average among the models. It might make sense to show the individual ROC curves in supplemental material; if they disagree substantially then you should consider whether there's something wrong.
The estimates of survival probability at time $t$, $S(t)$, are approximately normally distributed following a complementary log-log transformation, $\log(-\log(S(t))$. Calculate averages in that transformed scale, then back-transform.  A paper by Moscovici and Ratitch presented at the 2017 PharmaSUG conference  discusses how to include standard errors around pooled survival estimates.
